# How do I access all the nested data in the response from an API call and display it in a Jinja template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I’m building something with Python and Flask and Jinja templates that involves using data from an API call. Some of what comes back is nested inside objects (apologies if I get any terminology wrong, I’m quite new). For example, this is how I’m assigning what comes back in the response to instances of my Park model:

```
def show_parks():
    endpoint = "https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?limit=50&start=10&API_KEY=apikey"
    req = urllib.request.Request(endpoint)

    # Execute request and parse response
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    data = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))
    park_ids_in_db = [park.id for park in Park.query.all()]

    # Prepare and execute output
    for place in data["data"]:
        if place["designation"] == "National Park" and place["id"] not in park_ids_in_db:

            park = Park(
                id=place["id"], 
                name=place["fullName"], 
                code=place["parkCode"], 
                description=place["description"], 
                ent_fees_cost=place["entranceFees"][0]["cost"], 
                ent_fees_description=place["entranceFees"][0]["description"], 
                ent_fees_title=place["entranceFees"][0]["title"], 
                ent_passes_cost=place["entrancePasses"][0]["cost"], 
                ent_passes_description=place["entrancePasses"][0]["description"], 
                ent_passes_title=place["entrancePasses"][0]["title"], 
                # activity=activityNames,
                activity=place["activities"][0]["name"], 
             # data for activities in the JSON response looks like this: 
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "09DF0950-D319-4557-A57E-04CD2F63FF42",
                    "name": "Arts and Culture"
                },
                {
                    "id": "FAED7F97-3474-4C21-AB42-FB0768A2F826",
                    "name": "Cultural Demonstrations"
                },
                {
                    "id": "13A57703-BB1A-41A2-94B8-53B692EB7238",
                    "name": "Astronomy"
                },
                {
                    "id": "D37A0003-8317-4F04-8FB0-4CF0A272E195",
                    "name": "Stargazing"
                },]
                state=place["states"], 
                phone=place["contacts"]["phoneNumbers"][0]["phoneNumber"], 
                directions_url=place["directionsUrl"], 
                hours=place["operatingHours"][0]["description"], 
                town=place["addresses"][0]["city"], 
                image_title=place["images"][0]["title"], 
                image_altText=place["images"][0]["altText"], 
                image_url=place["images"][0]["url"], 
                weather_info=place["weatherInfo"],)

            db.session.add(park)

    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('/logged_in_home.html', parks=Park.query.all())
```

Things like name and description just have one string in the response. But with something like activities, the response has an array with a bunch of objects for each activity. I want access to all those activities so I can list them all in a template. But if I do activity=place[“activities”][name”] without the [0] I get an error of ‘string indices must be integers.’ So I put that index of [0] and that gets around the error, but then I only have access to the first activity.

My first stab at getting access to all of them while avoiding that error was to create an empty string and add the activities to it with a for loop, then pass that string into statement where instances of Park are created (taking all the other attributes out here just to make it easier to read):

```
for place in data["data"]:
            
            activityNames = ""
            activities = place["activities"]
            for activity in activities:
                activityNames += activity

                park = Park(
                    activity=activityNames,
)
```

Then in my template I tried doing a for loop to go through the activities to display them:

```
Here are some activities you can do in the park:<br>
{% for activity in activityNames %}
    {{ park.activity }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

I don’t get an error when I load the template, but it ignores the activities, it just skips over them to the next thing. I can’t tell if I’m way off in my approach or on the right track. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Please show the input data structure and expected result. Seems like two (or more?) separate problems here.

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry for the newbie questions, but by input data structure do you mean the class Park from my models.py?

Comment: `place` is some sort of nested dictionary, probably parsed from JSON. You say you're having a problem with some of these nested chains like `place[“activities”][name”]` but without seeing `place`, it's anyone's guess as to how to fix it. All of this is before an instance of `Park` is built, because this is part of the initializer. Also, it seems odd to have to mush a bunch of strings together. Usually you use lists for that, or you make different object instances per element. So the result is pretty unclear. `activityNames` seems to be a string...? But then you're looping over it in jinja?

Comment: @ggorlen OK, I follow. `activityNames` is a string, yes, and I'm not surprised you're confused, because I was taking a stab in the dark at getting the names of all the activities to show up in the template. Someone suggested adding the activity names to an empty string in the route and passing it into where I'm creating Park instances, but then I realized I didn't know how to access those activities from the string in my template. I edited my post to add more to the code I was sharing, hopefully it clears up what `place` is.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still in the dark because I don't have your API key or your database. I still have no idea what data we're working with (`data['data']`) or the expected result. Please just hardcode it. If it's huge, please minimize it down to the simplest structure needed to illustrate the failure. I should be able to copy and paste the code so I can see the problem and fix it for you. Otherwise, there's no action I can take to help.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm so new to this I'm not entirely sure how to do what you're asking (and my brain is fried from working on this project all day), but I tried adding a sample of what the JSON response looks like. If that's not sufficient, I apologize. I really appreciate you trying to help, I always feel super grateful when really experienced people help me out as a beginner. Hopefully I can pay it forward down the road.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm totally confused. That structure you show has 2 keys per dict, but your code is using a dozen or so other keys like `"designation"`, `"activities"`, `"weatherInfo"`, `"operatingHours"`, etc. Some of these properties are nested dicts or lists themselves. Basically, present the question in such a way that the code is runnable. If I can't copy and paste the code to run and see whatever error you're seeing instantly, there's more work to be done on your end to prepare the question. It's impossible to answer this in its current state.

Comment: @ggorlen Is it possible for something like this to be runnable for someone else if I don't include the API key on here, which I'm under the impression you're not supposed to do? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. You can copy the result of the API call and hardcode it into the code, then remove the API call completely. `print(data["data"])` should give you a valid python list of dicts that can be pasted back into the code. In fact, even if there were no API key, doing this would be a useful step towards minimizing the problem, because you're eliminating part of the code that works and adds a third-party dependency and distraction at best. I suggest a read of the [mcve] article.